# Тестирование именованного запроса Oracle через локальную H2 базу

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, тестирование, h2

Стоит задача протестировать выполнение named query, который написан для работы с базой данных Oracle, через локально поднятую H2 базу. Для этого у нас есть специальный класс, который самостоятельно выполняет необходимую настройку H2 базы, все, что ему нужно это sql-скрипит, создающий и заполняющий необходимые таблицы и некоторые конфигурационные параметры, вроде `show_sql`, `hibernate_dialect` (у меня стоит H2, но пробовал ставить и Oracle), в свойствах этого класса стоит режим совместимости h2 с Oracle, тут проблем нет. База корректно поднимается, запрос выполняется, но проблема возникает в этом месте:

```
FIRST_VALUE(XXX) OVER (YYY)
```

Ошибка:

> Function "FIRST_VALUE" not found;

Погуглил что это за функция такая, оказалось она есть как в Oracle-диалекте, так и в H2, запрос составлен синаксически корректно, почему возникает проблема в этом моменте - не очень понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что в H2 функция FIRST_VALUE появилась в версии 1.4.198, в нашем же проекте была версия 1.4.195